# customer massive import

Tags: customer, import, programmatically

I am working on magento very custom.

Now i have created a script for the import customers. This script does more checks. 
Now... into the database there are 1400 customers. My script import into magento only 370.

The error message is:

Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable
Guru Meditation:

XID: 279928762

I think can by the max execution time.

i have insert this 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
set_time_limit(3600);
but it's still the problem.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try to run script using **shell** or **ssh** command.

Comment: you right. I need to execute the script with ssh or shell.

Comment: Is this work in your case ?

Comment: I'm working on it

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a varnish error. You will also require to adjust varnish timeouts.

On a side note, I do suggest imports are done via CLI so you don't have issues with varnish, nginx/apache based timeouts.